# Fx futures pairs

Tags: portfolio-management, futures, fx, pairs-trading

I want to setup a pairs trade with the Japanese yen as the quote currency and Mexican peso as the basis currency. (long MXP vs JPY)

2 /M6J contracts, notional is 1,250,000 JPY = 10966.5*2 = **21933** USD equivalent

1 /6M contract notional is 500,000 MXP = **23934.75** USD equivalent

Would I be short 2 /M6J and long 1 /6M? Would the volatility of this trade be roughly around the historical volatility of the japanese yen versus the mexican peso?

Comment: Your calculation seems correct. Because $21933 \approx 23934$ you would have little exposure to USD and would be for all practical purposes long MXP and short JPY. Maybe someone else can double-check.

Comment: Great! How about the volatility portion?

Comment: You can download the data from the NY Fed (there are other free sources) and do the calculation for realised vol. https://apps.newyorkfed.org/markets/autorates/fxrates/external/home. No guarantee future realised will look similar, of course.

Comment: is there a way to get non-dollar fx rates from the fed? I can only find them in dollar terms

Comment: Just calculate the cross.

Comment: BTW noob2 did you mean to say that I'd be long more pesos than yen?